# how can you translate the statement if(isalpha(c)) from C++ to MIPS?

Tags: c++, function, mips, translate

I am trying to translate the statement `if(isalpha(c))`, where `c` is a char variable, from C++ to MIPS assembly. I tried to google it, but I could not find an answer. Does anyone have any idea?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: A skill programmers should find invaluable is the ability to _program,_ or at least try. I despair for the programming industry where everyone just tries to build their application from snippets fond on Google.

Comment: @paxdiablo-- I also find tutorials from other schools/professors on google. That's what I do first if I think that my notes are not complete. When I say "I google it" it does not necessarily implies that I am looking for code written by others, otherwise, I don't need to come to stackoverflow.com, because it is also found on google with all possible answers with codes. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What's your problem; that you don't know what `isalpha()` does or that you don't know MIPS assembly? Or neither? Or both?

Comment: we have covered if statement and function in MIPS. my problem is trying to translate the "if" statement where the condition is "the return of the function isalpha(c)". I am not sure if I am close to the answer, but I am thinking about doing something like: $v0=isalpha(c), then compare $v0 with the Ascii code range of digits.

Comment: `isalpha` uses a lookup table of character traits, you would need to replicate this to get exactly the same functionality. If all you care about is the roman characters A-Z you can do it easily by testing the value of `c` (e.g. if (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') or (c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z'))

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to demonstrate one possible way, which is not efficient or "cool", but it's simple.

So, you want an equivalent of this C block:

```
if (isalpha(c))
{
    /* Do stuff... */
}
```

Which is like this, considering how `isalpha()` works:

```
if (('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z'))
{
    /* Do stuff... */
}
```

But there are no "block" structures in assembly. Everything is a *jump* (or a `goto` in C, which you should *never* use.) So, to get closer to the assembly version, we might modify our C code to use a jump:

```
if (!(('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')))
    goto AfterStuff;

/* Do stuff... */

AfterStuff:
```

Note that we are jumping over the "Do stuff" part if the *reverse* of our condition was true.
Now, assuming we know that `'A'` < `'Z'` < `'a'` < `'z'` (the ASCII codes are, respectively: 65, 90, 97, 122,) then we can rewrite the above code like this:

```
if (c < 65)
    goto AfterStuff;
if (c <= 90)
    goto DoStuff;
if (c < 97)
    goto AfterStuff;
if (c > 122)
    goto AfterStuff;

DoStuff:
/* Do stuff... */

AfterStuff:
```

Note that if `c` is less than 'A', we jump after the stuff. But if after comparing c and 'A', we find out that c is not only greater or equal to 'A' (because we didn't jump away,) but it's also less than or equal to 'Z', we jump directly to the "stuff" and don't check anything else. Also, the operands of the last `blt` instruction are reversed.

The assembly gets a little complicated, because we have to load the required immediates into registers and whatnot. Here's the code:

```
  lb    $t0, ($s0)            # assuming address of c is in s0 register

  addi  $t1, $zero, 65        # set t1 = 'A'
  blt   $t0, $t1, AfterStuff  # if (c < 'A') goto AfterStuff

  addi  $t1, $zero, 90        # set t1 = 'Z'
  ble   $t0, $t1, DoStuff     # if (c <= 'Z') goto DoStuff

  addi  $t1, $zero, 97        # set t1 = 'a'
  blt   $t0, $t1, AfterStuff  # if (c < 'a') goto AfterStuff

  addi  $t1, $zero, 122       # set t1 = 'z'
  blt   $t1, $t0, AfterStuff  # if ('z' < c) goto AfterStuff

DoStuff:
  # Do whatever you want to do

AfterStuff:
```

I believe the above works, but I absolutely can't be sure. It has been more than a decade since I wrote any MIPS assembly code (or any other code for a MIPS) and I was never very proficient anyways.